# How do I xcopy only specific subdirectories and files within subdirectories

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy

Here is an example of what I have:

```
c:\top\dir1\dir2\dir3\desired_dir1\desired_file.abc
c:\top\dir1\dir2\dir3\desired_dir1\unwanted.file

c:\top\dir1\dir2\dir3\unwanted_dir2\some.file

c:\top\dir1\dir2\dir3\desired_dir2\desired_file.abc

c:\top\dir4\dir2\dir3\desired_dir3\desired_file.abc
c:\top\dir4\dir2\dir3\desired_dir3\unwanted.file

c:\top\dir4\dir2\dir3\unwanted_dir4\some.file
c:\top\dir4\dir2\dir3\desired_dir4\desired_file.abc
```

I want to preserve the structure under c:\top\ and I only need the directories with the desired_file.abc.  In unix I would probably to something like grepping the paths from ls, but I only have xcopy since I am running in Visual Studio.

I want to end up with:

```
c:\DESTINATION\dir1\dir2\dir3\desired_dir1\desired_file.abc

c:\DESTINATION\dir1\dir2\dir3\desired_dir2\desired_file.abc

c:\DESTINATION\dir4\dir2\dir3\desired_dir3\desired_file.abc

c:\DESTINATION\dir4\dir2\dir3\desired_dir4\desired_file.abc
```

Comment: The `xcopy` command provides a `/exclude` parameter which can be used to skip unwanted files/folders. Did you try using it already?

Comment: I have not.  There are all kinds of files I don't want, so I was hoping to use a white list like *.abc.  The hard part is that I want the structure above it too, just not _all_ the folders.

Comment: Do unwanted files all share a common name/extension pattern?

Comment: Not just one, many different patterns, and they may often change.  It is **much** safer to include the ones I want.

Comment: I see. Then you should probably create a batch script to build a whitelist, and then `xcopy` only the dedired folders/files. You could then [run the batch script from Visual Studio](http://www.rickglos.com/post/How-to-run-windows-batch-files-from-Visual-Studio-2010-Solution-Explorer.aspx).

Comment: There is no solution with xcopy only?

Comment: The only solution would be explicitly copying each file you need, one by one.